# Oracle string compare in query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two string and want to know, if in alphabetically sorted list the string2 is before string1, is the same, or comes after string1.

Something like `STRCMP (string1, string2)` for MySql.

Is there some kind of built in function, that isn't that popular, or should I use a non-function approach manually comparing each char (if that is even considerable)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string1 > string2

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: The Title and Tags include that I'm using Oracle..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is `<`.  You can use boolean comparators to get "alphabetic" ordering.  I put that in quotes because it depends on the collation of the strings, but it is usually reasonable.

In a `where` clause:

```
where string1 < string2
```

If you want a value, then this works in both Oracle and MySQL:

```
select (case when string1 < string2 then 1 else 0 end) as string_compare_flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to consider nulls and case.

In PL/SQL you could do something like this...

```
declare 

  BEFORE CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := -1;
  AFTER CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  SAME CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 0;

  NULLS_FIRST CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(9);
  NULLS_LAST CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(127);

  string1 varchar2(100);
  string2 varchar2(100);

  result pls_integer;

  --If this was a function then these would be your input parameters
  inputString1 varchar2(100) := 'A'; --try null here
  inputString2 varchar2(100) := 'b';
  --swap this over if you want nulls first
  nullPos VARCHAR2(1) := NULLS_LAST; --try swapping to NULLS_FIRST

begin

  string1 := upper(nvl(inputString1,nullPos));
  string2 := upper(nvl(inputString2,nullPos));

  result := case when string1 < string2 then BEFORE 
             when string1 = string2 then SAME
             else AFTER end;

  dbms_output.put_line(result);           

end;
```

The values chosen for NULLS_FIRST and NULLS_LAST are just arbitrary but outside of the standard a-z A-Z so that a null value will get placed either before or after a non null one, and so two null values will return 0 (same).

If you aren't bothered about case i.e A comes after b then you can ignore the upper function code.

You could put the plsql code (or similar) in a function and call it from your SQL or you could do

```
SELECT case when upper(nvl(string1,CHR(127))) < upper(nvl(string2,CHR(127))) then -1
            when upper(nvl(string1,CHR(127))) = upper(nvl(string2,CHR(127))) then 0
            else 1 
            end
...
```